# expected an identifier when including windows h (C)

Tags: c, enums, typedef

when including the windows.h library , i suddenly get this weird error

NOTE: when i didnt use windows.h, the program worked just fine. this is the code:

[image: typedeferror]

only the true and false enums are not compiling.. why is that?
thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly because `TRUE` and `FALSE` are already defined as macros in `"windows.h"` (or included by it).

So somewhere there is, for example,

```
#define TRUE (1)
```

That code gets replaced inside your `enum` declaration raising a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

TRUE and FALSE are usually #defined as -1 and 0 (or perhaps 1 and 0). So when the first pass of the compiler does the substitution, the next pass of the compiler is given:

```
typedef enum{ -1, 0 }bools;
```

which is obviously not valid syntax.